# Original paper for Young's double slit experiments

Tags: physics, reference-request

I'm trying to find the original papers describing Young's double slit experiments including his experimental set-ups and findings. I've tried looking and all I can find is http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/63005#page/498/mode/1up and http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/92/12 But neither are papers describing the experiments.